# Emacs call-process stumbles upon supplied args content

Tags: process, emacs

I'm puzzled by unexpected behavior of a call-process call.

Here's a little function:

```
(defun work-in-progress()
    "run ledger report and output result in current buffer.
The intention is to run following command (works perfectly from shell):
`ledger -U csv --sort date --file ledger-file child`
where ledger-file is a known and defined variable.
The problem is that the command fails with:
`Error: Illegal option -`
"
    (interactive)
    (cd ledger-dir)
    (setq child "peter")
    (setq parms "-U csv --sort date --file")
    (setq prog "ledger") ; should be found via path variable or so
    (call-process prog nil t t parms ledger-file child)
  )
```

I've played around with the sequence of the ledger command options, but emacs always seems to complain about the first option or all options in the parms variable:

e.g.

```
(setq parms "--sort date -U csv --file")
```

results in

```
Error: Illegal option --sort date -U csv --file
```

iso

```
Error: Illegal option -
```

The ledger cli program isn't fussy about arguments sequence, both described option sequences work perfectly well when calling ledger at the command line.

This truly puzzles me. The documentation reads

```
call-process program &optional infile destination display &rest args
```

and infile is set to nil, destination as well as display are t, so why doesn'it grok the content of args variable?

Any help, correction and/or suggestion would be sincerely appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The tail of the list should be a sequence of strings, each corresponding to one argument.

```
    (setq parms '("-U" "csv" "--sort" "date" "--file"))
    (setq prog "ledger")
    (apply #'call-process prog nil t t (append parms '(ledger-file child)))
```

You need `apply` to make the result of `append` into a continuation of the static list of arguments to `call-process`.

I had to guess what `ledger-file` and `child` are; if they are not strings, you need to convert them to strings.

To briefly recapitulate how the shell parses arguments, the command line

```
echo foo "bar $baz" 'quux $baz'
```

gets turned into the string array

```
'("echo" "foo" "bar <<value of baz>>" "quux $baz")
```

(to use a Lispy notation) and passed as arguments to `execlp`.

Comment: That causes following error upon execution:    "Wrong type argument: stringp, 45"

Comment: I had to guess what `ledger-file` and `child` are; convert those to strings if they are not. I'll update the answer to mention this.

Comment: they are strings resp. "~/ledger/file.ledger" and "peter"

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to pass each parameter as a separate string:

```
(defun work-in-progress()
    "run ledger report and output result in current buffer. "
    (interactive)
    (cd ledger-dir)
    (setq child "peter")
    (setq prog "ledger") ; should be found via path variable or so
    (call-process prog nil t t "--sort" "date" "-U" "csv" "--file" ledger-file child)
)
```